# Firebase Authentication not recognising my password using React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make a signup page for new users. The data is supposed to be sent straight to the firebase database immediately after registration. The problem is that firebase keeps giving me "password must be bigger than 6 characters" error. I don't know why because I put in more than enough letters.

Thank you very much

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import NavbarT from './UnivComp/navbar.js';
import FooterT from './UnivComp/footer.js';
import fire from './config/firebased.js';
import writeUserData from './config/rwfire.js'
import firebase from 'firebase';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Apppr extends Component {
  constructor(props) {

      super(props);
      this.signup = this.signup.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        subject:'',
        location:'',
        telephone:'',
        brief:'',
        youtubevid:'',

      };

    }

    signup(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(e);
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword("galbeedmok@gmail.com","gem")
        .then((res) => {
            firebase.database().ref('users/' + res.user.uid).set({
              email:   this.state.email,
              password:   this.state.password,
              subject:   this.state.subject,
              location:   this.state.location,
              telephone:   this.state.telephone,
              brief:   this.state.brief,
              youtubevid:  this.state.youtubevid,
            });
        });
}

  render() {
    const { signup } = this.props;

    return (

      <div>
      <NavbarT/>
      <form class = " clearin container  mx-auto">
        <div class="form-group pb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><h3>Email address</h3></label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control input-md" id="exampleInputEmail1" value={this.state.email} onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })} aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email"/>
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
      <div class="form-group pb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1"><h3>Password</h3></label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control input-md" id="exampleInputPassword1" value={this.state.password}  onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })} placeholder="Password"/>
        {console.log(this.state.password)}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2 "><h3>What subjects do you tutor?</h3></label>
        <select multiple class="form-control form-control-lg" value={this.state.subject} onChange={e => this.setState({ subject : "Physics" })} id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
        <option>Physics</option>
        <option>Chemistry</option>
        <option>Human Biology</option>
        <option>Mathematics</option>
        <option>ESL</option>
        <option>English</option>
        </select>
        </div>

          <div class="mb-5 form-group pb-3 ">
            <label><h3>Where abouts are you located?</h3></label>
            <input  class="form-control input-md" value={this.state.location} onChange={e => this.setState({ location: e.target.value })} aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="e.g Claremont"/>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group pb-3 ">
        <label for="example-tel-input">Telephone</label>
        <input class="form-control input-md" type="tel" placeholder="1-(555)-555-5555" id="example-tel-input" value={this.state.telephone} onChange={e => this.setState({ telephone: e.target.value })}/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group pb-3">
    <label for="exampleTextarea"><h3>Give students a brief description of yourself.</h3></label>
    <textarea class="form-control input-md" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3" value={this.state.brief} onChange={e => this.setState({ brief: e.target.value })}></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group pb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><h3>A youtube video depicting your work</h3></label>
    <input  class="form-control input-md"  aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlRObEeuuJM" value={this.state.youtubevid} onChange={e => this.setState({ youtubevid: e.target.value })}/>

    </div>
<br/>

<button onClick={console.log(this.state.password)} style={{marginLeft: '25px'}} class="btn btn-success">Signup</button>

        </form>

      <FooterT/>

      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Apppr;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from Firebase Authentication, which you call with:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword("galbeedmok@gmail.com","gem")
```

And `"gem"` is shorter than 6 characters.

Comment: I FORGOT ABOUT DEBUGGING OMG THANKYOU SO MUCH!

Comment: scratch that , now it just doesn't do anything. Doesn't print error but doesn't add to database

Comment: can we see `import fire from './config/firebased.js'` to see if you've initialised things correctly or can you confirm that the connection is not the problem.

Comment: The error you reported in your question is because of the problem I point out in my answer and is caused by how you call the Firebase *Authentication* API. There may also be problems in your interactions with the Firebase *Database* API, but those are unrelated. The first thing to usually do there is check your log output for any errors. If that doesn't solve it, check if you can write *anything* to the database in another place. If that doesn't solve it, open a new question with the **minimal, complete** code that reproduces this second problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys the error was a combination of me setting my default values

```
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword("galbeedmok@gmail.com","gem")
```

and as well as my handler being faulty. I have used individual handling of my instances and it has begun working:

```
      <div class="form-group pb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1"><h3>Password</h3></label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control input-md" id="exampleInputPassword1" value={this.state.password}  onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })} placeholder="Password"/>
    {console.log(this.state.password)}
    </div>
```